# Meanshift: distance from cluster centroid

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, mean-shift

I am trying to get the distance of all member data points in a cluster from that cluster centroid in meanshift clustering. Like in kmeans gives the distance via transform() method but unfortunately I am having trouble finding any such for meanshift.

Comment: Add source codes to solve your problem. What did you try on what is your dataset? Your question is so general.

Comment: I wanted to calculate the distance between 2 points in 3D (centroid and member datapoints). KMeans have a method for that but not MeanShift I guess. I am using euclidean distance formula for that now.